How can I export an animation containing a single pose and keep the keyframes intact?
I have an animation with a single pose in it that I want to export as an FBX and bring into Unity. I've determined that the issue is on the Blender export, not the Unity import.
The animation I'm working with has 3 keyframes (one at the beginning, middle, and end) all with the same values on them to hold the pose for 20 frames. What I want is for Blender to only export my authored keyframes, but that's proven difficult so far. I've tried a combination of different export settings, and none of them give the results I'm looking for. Here's what I've tried:

These export settings do export the animated pose properly, however Blender forces start/end keys on every animated bone and blend shape even if they did not originally contain any keyframes. This is an issue especially for blend shapes because it prevents me from controlling those values via code, as the code-driven values are overwritten when playing the animation in Unity.



I tried disabling Force Start/End Keying (like in the image below), but that results in the animation not exporting at all! I think Blender is removing keyframes that are too similar to one another, which ends up erasing all animation data in this case.



To fix the issue of all the keyframes getting removed, I played around with the Simplify value to see if that might help anything. The lowest non-zero value I could use was 0.01 and that still had no effect. If I export the animation with a Simplify value of 0.00, Blender exports the animation with keyframes on every single frame for every bone and blend shape on the model even if there was no animation there to begin with. Again, this is an issue because I want to control the blend shape via code, and the animation overrides the blend shape value to 0.0.


If anyone has any tips or thoughts on how to get this working I'd really appreciate it!
